# Why won't my image name convert to lowercase in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<img src="/images/<?php strtolower(the_title()); ?>.jpg" border="0" >
```

Answer (score 4):

Wordpress [the_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) function echoes the title by default. You need to set the echo argument to false and echo the lowercase output yourself.

```
<img src="/images/<?php echo strtolower(the_title('','',false)); ?>.jpg" border="0" />
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! I love you Conrad!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `the_title()` actually echo's out the title since you don't have an echo statement in your snippet. So your call to `strtolower()` is basically doing nothing. You'll need to capture the output of `the_title()` then you can convert it to lower case.

```
ob_start();
the_title();
$title = $template = ob_get_clean();
<img src="/images/<?php echo strtolower($title); ?>.jpg" border="0" />
```

Comment: Is there a way around that? I'm a total PHP noob.

Comment: yeah, this is an epic hack, don't do this.